# SimpleDateFormat is giving future date as formatted Date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

```
    String timestamp = "2020-05-22 12:58:04.517123+05:30"; 
    Date d = null;
    try {
        d = ext.parse(timestamp);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } */
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").parse(timestamp);
    System.out.println(date);
    // o/p : Fri May 22 13:06:41 IST 2020
```

we can see that SimpleDateFormat is producing Future Date. What might be the reason ?

Comment: Your example data from first and last lines seem to be from two different scenarios.

Comment: How many second is `517123ms` ?  Maybe you mean `"2020-05-22 12:58:04.517+05:30"`

Comment: Do you understand that `Date::toString` tells a lie? That method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating text to represent the value of the object. This has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: So what is the correct way to get the actual time in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `java.time.OffsetDateTime`

You have an input and a formatting pattern that both use [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond). The `Date` type is limited to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond).

You should not be using the terrible `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. Use only *java.time* classes.

Edit your input text to comply with the ISO 8601 standard. Replace the SPACE in the middle with `T`.

```
String input = "2020-05-22 12:58:04.517123+05:30".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Comment: @RaviKumarRavanam  No, I don’t know GIS.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `java.time` for this, do it. Do it like in the answer given by @BasilBorque or provide a pattern that parses `String`s of the given format directly without replacing the whitespace with a `T` to make it the ISO pattern:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String timestamp = "2020-05-22 12:58:04.517123+05:30";
    // parse the string to an OffsetDateTime using a matching pattern
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(timestamp,
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXXXX"));
    // print the result in the default (ISO) pattern
    System.out.println(odt);
}
```

The result looks like

```
2020-05-22T12:58:04.517123+05:30
```

and is formattable in many different ways.

Answer (score 1):

In `12:58:04.517123+05:30` 517123 is considered millisecond, which translates to roughly 8 minutes 37 seconds. That's the reason your time is changing. Another important aspect of Date is that it has no concept of timezone, it's merely tells no. of milliseconds from epoch. So when you do toString() it display time in JVM timezone.